# The root of the polynomial $f(x)=x^n-kx^{n-1}-kx^{n-2}-\cdots-kx-k$ of the largest magnitude?

Tags: polynomials

There is a root, say $\lambda$, of the polynomial $f(x)=x^n-kx^{n-1}-kx^{n-2}-\cdots-kx-k$ between k and k+1 (by the intermediate value theorem), where $n,k$ are integers and $n,k\geq 2$. Is $\lambda$ the root of $f(x)$ of the largest magnitude?
Specifically, the numerical results show that $f(x)$ has only one positive real root $\lambda$ between $k$ and $k+1$ and zero (resp., one) negative real root in the case that $n$ is odd (resp., even), and all the other roots of $f(x)$ are complex with magnitude less than $\lambda$. The problem is how to prove this?

Answer (score 1):

The assertions about the uniqueness of the positive root and the number of negative roots are easy to prove using [Descartes' rule of signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs). The sequence of coefficients of your polynomial has just one change of signs; therefore, there is exactly one positive root. Furthermore, 
  $$ (x-1)f(x) = x^{n+1}-x^n-k(x^n-1) = x^{n+1} - (k+1)x^n + k, $$ 
whence 
  $$ (-x-1)f(-x)=(-1)^{n+1}x^{n+1}+(-1)^{n+1}(k+1)x^n+k. $$
If $n$ is odd, then the sequence of the coefficients does not have any sign changes; therefore $(-x-1)f(-x)$ does not have any positive roots, meaning that $f(x)$ does not have negative roots. If $n$ is even, there is one sign change; hence, one negative root of $f(x)$.